# Include JQuery-Ui in Angular 7 project for external .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui

I have an Angular 7 project and I am trying to include the JQuery-Ui plugin. I have both JQuery and the plugin installed and added to scripts array in angular.json. I have all of my JQuery functions in a jquery.js file i have added to assets folder and imported said file into my component.ts file. JQuery is working but i am not able to use plugin functions. I tried importing 'jquery-ui' to jquery.js file as well with no positive results. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

angular.json

```
"scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "../node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"
          ]
```

jquery.js

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#page_top').children().hover(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({color: 'red'}, 200)
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({color: 'blue'}, 200)
    }
);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting? Is your index.html including jQuery? From what i remember if you include it in `scripts` it will automatically do that for you. If you go that route, you can do

```
//component.ts
declare var $; //you can now use $ just like normal jQuery
@Component({})
```

I generally don't use jQuery with Angular, but had to do this in the past for a project.

Comment: i am not logging any errors. I haven't included any <script> tags for jquery or plugin on templates if thats what your asking. They are included in scripts array in angular.json and i am able to use jquery itself just fine but i cannot declare var $; as my jquery functions are not in a .ts file..

Comment: Why not use Angular's built in Animate Module? Even if you get jQuery to work with Angular the way you are doing it I can see some change detection issues happening where jQuery eventsay run outside Angular's zone

Comment: I have already built many functions this way using jquery for this particular project I don't wish to familiarize myself with more angular modules at this time tho it is good to know for future projects. I understand it is not ideal but would just like to find a workaround for the plugins at this time!